# Why can neither mods nor CMs forcibly create synonyms from a big tag to a small tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonym-process

While trying to synonymize [hapijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs) (originally around 1.2k prior to a merge) into [hapi.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapi.js) (originally 53), all synonym tools failed with this error message:

> Can't create synonym; the 'hapijs' tag appears more than 1.25 times the 'hapi.js' tag

As an attempted hack, I tried merging before making the synonym, but doing so did not update the question count. The count the synonyms use is visible [on the synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hapi.js/synonyms), **not** the count on the question list. Until the update hits some time tonight, these two counts aren't the same. The one on the synonym page is currently stuck at 53.

The merger errored out on the synonym part with "an unknown error", but I assume it's the same error the pure synonymization runs into. However, this isn't really a big deal when the existence of the error is the problem, and not how it's presented in a different part of the UI.

After a chat with Catija (community manager), she ran into the exact same error I did, and couldn't create the synonym either.

While I'm sure this error has its reasons for normal users, why can't mods or CMs force the synonym creation? At the very least, CMs should be able to force it -- they have ways around plenty of other limits mods can't get around already.

Comment: At least for normal users, the reasons [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170077/241919): "*The ratio is there for a reason - so that low-count tags don't become masters of high-count tags.*", [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58855/241919): "*This protection is in place to ensure that the most popular tags always take preference.*"

Comment: @AndrewT. That's why this question is explicitly scoped to mods and CMs who should have access to the "I know what I'm doing" button.

Comment: Yeah, or outright bypass it directly.

Comment: If it's not going to be a common action for admins, my general preference is that anything normal users aren't permitted to do because it's normally a mistake should trigger a confirmation even on admin views.

Comment: Create a synonym and then on the synonyms page swap it.

Comment: For reference, I got that "unknown error" message you mentioned ("An unknown error has occurred; please try again later.") – and the same bug on the Tag Synonyms page that you describe in your "As an attempted hack" paragraph – when attempting to merge a much smaller tag (or a default tag with 0 questions) into an existing tag... So I don't think it's necessarily due to the main issue you're reporting (i.e. the error message "the 'hapijs' tag appears more than 1.25 times the 'hapi.js' tag" when creating a synonym).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should now be fixed (please comment here if you are still seeing it). The tag count ratio is now bypassed in the case of creating a synonym while merging tags.

> Mod merges some tags
> and creates a synonym
> all should be good now