# Make [azure-sqldw] a synonym of [azure-sql-data-warehouse]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

It looks like something similar was asked about 6 years ago in the question [Merge the two tags used for Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335364/merge-the-two-tags-used-for-microsoft-azure-sql-data-warehouse), however, this is with a different set of tags for the same technology.

[azure-sqldw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sqldw) currently has 410 questions, and has both usage guidance and a excerpt. In all of this it references to "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" rather than "SQLDW".

[azure-sql-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-data-warehouse), however, has 230 questions, and its guidance and excerpt are the same text for both.

I, personally, feel that the latter tag ([azure-sql-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-data-warehouse)) is the better name for it, even though the former has more questions. The fact, however, that [azure-sqldw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sqldw) references "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" in its guidance and excerpt further cements this. Likely the usage guidance and excerpt should be copied from [azure-sqldw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sqldw) to [azure-sql-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sql-data-warehouse).

Comment: I'd assume this request is *both* a merge and synonymize, since I'm worried [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418662/2821954) may hinder in making a tag synonym only without merging.

Comment: Yes, effectively, @AndrewT.

Comment: @Larnu There's a new discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423231/microsoft-azure-collective-launch-and-proposed-tag-changes) that relates to these tags

Comment: Since both these tags have now been merged into [azure-synapse] as of the discussion that Berthold linked above (making this proposal obsolete), I'm closing this request as a duplicate of that post.